# Unable to access nested object in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to access single elements within an object and I keep getting an error.

Here is my React Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { fetchCoin } from "../redux/actions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ViewCoin extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCoin(this.props.match.params.symbol);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Props:", this.props.coin);
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>View Item Page</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    coin: state.coins.coin
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCoin })(ViewCoin);
```

This code returns the following object:

```js
{
    "BTC": {
        "urls": {
            "website": [
                "https://bitcoin.org/"
            ],
            "twitter": [],
            "reddit": [
                "https://reddit.com/r/bitcoin"
            ],
            "message_board": [
                "https://bitcointalk.org"
            ],
            "announcement": [],
            "chat": [],
            "explorer": [
                "https://blockchain.info/",
                "https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/",
                "https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/blocks"
            ],
            "source_code": [
                "https://github.com/bitcoin/"
            ]
        },
        "logo": "https://s2.coinmarketcap.com/static/img/coins/64x64/1.png",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable"
        ],
        "category": "coin"
    }
}
```

When trying to access the coin name, for example, I issue the command:

console.log(this.props.coin.BTC.name);

I get the error: Cannot read property 'BTC' of undefined

I tested accessing values in this object outside of React and I am able to access the different values. How would one access a nested object like this using React.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks fine, but you need a constructor. `constructor(props){ super(props) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's likely happening is the first time that component renders `coin` is undefined.  When the action returns, the props are updated, the component re-renders and `coin` is logged out.

Do something like this in render and it should work:

```
this.props.coin && console.log('coin name:', this.props.coin.BTC.name)
```

Comment: glad to hear it!